# Do not run this code on posts with a specific tag!

Tags: tags, conditional-content

This is sort of complicated.

I am looking for some php help related to WordPress blog.

The basic requirement is that some HTML code (ad code) is not supposed to run on posts with a specific tag. In simple terms... I do not want to run ads in posts which have a specific tag!

How can it be accomplished?

I believe this would use this WordPress function:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag

I am not very proficient at PHP. I suppose this can be easily used to run specific code if the post has a specific tag. I want to do the opposite!

Comment: Do you have any code that you can show - might be easier to amend what you already have.

Comment: Actually I have been using PHP codes that detect the URL for similar requirements. But WordPress tags are not detectable using the URL of the post. Hence the problem. I have added some more info in the post. Please check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of basic PHP. You are correct in choice of function, you merely need to reverse the condition with [logical *Not* operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
if( !has_tag('test') ) {

}
```

Comment: oh lol - has_tag - forgot about that!

Comment: @anu it helped that it was right there in the question ;)

Comment: i actually added that a bit later. so anu might have missed it! this code seems to be working. i need to test it a bit more because of the extensive caching being done on the site! thanks guys!

Comment: yup - it wasn't there in the original question - i added a longwinded piece of code using get_the_tags() and iterating through with foreach - deleted ;)

Comment: get_the_tags() did not work for me. must have done something wrong. even if it did, it would have been pretty bad on the server because the blog in question has way too many tags and fetching each of them would have resulted in a server meltdown!

Comment: a question guys. now that the ad code is placed between the conditional tag code (which is only relevant if the visitor is on a post page and not homepage)... it would only get processed on single post pages? coz the ad code is not processing on home page now.

Comment: @OperaManiac actually scratch that, it should work for home page as well... try `var_dump( !has_tag('test') );` on home page and see what it resolves to.